# Elements displaying in reverse order on webpage in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In laravel `/resources/view/layout` folder, I have `header.blade.php` and `footer.blade.php`.

I have another file in `/resources/view` named `page1.blade.php`.

page1 is `@extends('layout.haeder')` `@extends('layout.footer')`

When I see http://127.0.0.1:8000/page1

problem is all elements are shown in reverse order. It displays from top to bottom; shows footer at the first place then the header. What should I do?

**resources/view/page1**

```
@extends('layout.header')
@extends('layout.footer')
```

**routs/web**

```php
Route::get('/page1', function () {
    return view('page1');
});
```

Comment: please try to use @include directive instead of extend

Comment: really you should create a 'partials' folder in the 'views' directory and then create these as partials, not as layouts - then you use @include('partials.header') and @include('partials.footer'), as you are creating partials/components, not page layouts

Comment: what is diffrents between partials and layouts ?

Comment: In page1.blade.php how you are using the other content with header and footer?

Comment: its nothing .. just  a empty page that call other pages to display a single page .. its for practice tho ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inside `/resources/view/layout` create a new blade file called for example `main.blade.php`.
   This is your **layout**. 
   Depends on your need it should be something like this:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
@include('partials.header')
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

2. Inside `main.blade.php` we used `@include(partials.header)` which is basically a blade file reside at `/resources/view/partials` and it is a **partial** so you can use it multiple time (for example in another layout)
   It can be includes something like this (Or anything you want):

```php
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Nav 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Nav 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Nav 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

3. In your `page1.blade.php` you can *extend* (Use) the layout you built and add it's unique *content* (Which is replace the part `@yield('content')` in `main.blade.php` layout)
   So it can be something like this:

```php
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content)
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>this is page content ... </p>
@endsection
```

4. In the end when you type *page1* in your browser Laravel renders you a page with contents below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Nav 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Nav 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Nav 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>this is page content ... </p>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: You can learn more about layouts and partials in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade)

Comment: partials create layouts and layouts create pages that is a **frame**  could call content respectively as we like.  got it  .. thanks

Comment: But whatever we use `@extends` the page seems read from bottom to top ... why it would behave like that ? when we should use `@extends` or `@include` ?

Comment: No @extend does not reverse the page. that's happens because you use `@extend` twice. You muse use `@extend` only one time per page and you can use `@include` as many time you want. `@include` is basically a code that you can paste on your code multiple time.